# how should is properly use this array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

I'm sorry if, for my bad English, i was trying a program who use a calc_vet_struct for try find the first number bigger than the previous one, my code for the struct and define it is :

```
constexpr int n = 50;
struct dati
{
    float val;
    int rig1;
    int col1;
};
typedef dati VS[n];
```

and i declered

```
VS calc_vett_struct(mat, int, int);
```

as my subprogram then in my main called it doing :

```
VS S;
S = calc_vett_struct(m, rig, col);
```

and created it in this way:

```
    VS calc_vett_struct(mat m, int rig, int col)
{
    VS p;
    for (int i = 0; i < rig; i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < col - 1; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] > m[i][j + 1] && found = true)
            {
                p[i].val = m[i][j];
                p[i].rig1 = i;
                p[i].col1 = j;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

hope is enough understandble and hope you can help me, if something is not clear please ask it.

the error is : `function cannot return a matrix`

Comment: C-array is not copiable, use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Typo: `&& found = true` you mean `==` ? but then you never enter the condition... `!=` perhaps ?

Comment: @Jarod42 it should be **==**  , I'm really sorry for my distraction error

Comment: @Jarod42 i'm really sorry but i'm not sure what you mean with "C-array is not copiable, use std::array instead"

Comment: He means that `S = calc_vett_struct` tries to return and copy a c-style array. This cannot be done.  For one thing, `VS p;` is a local variable. It expires at the end of the function and any copying would take place AFTER it no longer exists.

Comment: @user4581301 can you give me some examples of how i can make it work?

Comment: [Documentation for `std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). There are good usage examples at the bottom of the page.